# How to populate a formatted String using an Array List

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I am looking to format a String using an ArrayList which Strings, and integers within it. I can populate the same formatted String using an array. However this is not very useful because an Array can not contain both a String and an int. After creating an array list I found that my string will not be populated, unlike the case with an array. What are my options?

**Array**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String name = "Varun";
        String description = "cool";
        String [] string_array = new String[2];
        string_array[0] = name;
        string_array[1] = description;
        String works = String.format("Hi my name is %s and I am %s",string_array);
        System.out.println(works);
     }
}
```

**Array List**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String name = "Varun";
        int age = 22;
        List <Object> string_list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        string_list.add(name);
        string_list.add(age);
        String works = String.format("Hi my name is %s and I am %d years old",string_list);
        System.out.println(works);
     }
}
```

**How can I get my String to be formatted working using an ArrayList**

Comment: Very basic approach would be to invoke the toArray method of the List: String.format("... %s %d ...", string_list.toArray())

Comment: Write an answer to this question and I will mark this as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the list to an array using the toArray() method would achieve what you are after. You would need to be careful with how you use it to ensure the data within the list is of an appropriate format for formatting.

```
String value = String.format("Hi my name is %s and I am %d years old", string_list.toArray());
```